I found a simple op-amp circuit online, which confused me
The following circuit is simple. Due to its short output to input, the output will follow the input.
Besides that, I would like to understand the op-amp behavior, which is confusing me.
As I understand, the op-amp output will act as negative feedback till the input rises to 2.5V and, from that point, as a comparator, that is right?
At Vin -5V ~ 2.5V, the op-amp output will follow the Input/Output voltage minus the diode drop. That is, at -5V output, the op-amp output will be -4.3V.
If all the above is correct,

why does the 2.5V have no effect during the Vin = -5V ~ 2.5V?
is it not a differential op-amp during the negative feedback?
The op-amp output does not follow the difference between inverting and noninverting input?
Any logical explanation will be appreciated.

Thanks to all,
Y.A


you have input shorted to output here. You may mean that the '+' pin of the opamp is the circuit input. In that case, the circuit will only be able to follow a positive input signal; the output will be 0 for inputs below zero.
For positive inputs, it does act as a real opamp; for negative inputs, the opamp saturates (beaically the feedback loop effectively becomes open because the diode doesn't conduct) -- you can consider it a comparator.

Thak you for your answer,

Vin is connected to the inverting input. I made several simulations in LTSpice, and they act differently with different op-amps. I used the op77 and op727.

Vin is connected directly to both the output and to the inverting input.
That means that the output voltage will always equal in the input voltage
and (assuming it's connected to an ideal source) since the non-inverting input is connected to a fixed voltage, that there is no feedback. The 10k resistor also does nothing if it's connected to an ideal source.
So the output of the op-amp will be railed at or near +10 for Vin < 2.5V and near -10 for Vin > 2.5V if we assume the op-amp output current is limited.
That is not very interesting.
However the op-amp will attempt to drive the input to 2.5V, and is able to drive current through the diode iff Vin < 2.5V.
If you add a resistor in series with the input voltage you'll get more interesting behavior.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
In this case, the for inputs < 5V the output voltage is 2.5v and for inputs >= 5V the output voltage is Vin/2.

The 2:1 ratio is because I arbitrarily chose a 10kΩ source resistance. If you pick something lower, then the ratio will be closer to 1:1 but it can never quite get there because the output current of the op-amp is limited (and therefore its ability to 'fight' the current from the input through the added resistor).

Thank you for the answer,

The ratio of the 2:1 is the region of the resistor divider, that is (10k*10k)/(10k+10k) = 1/2(10k).

Yes, that is correct.

Hi how can the output go to either rail when the input is tied directly to the output?
